# How to deserialize an XML file to its own unique class?

Tags: java, polymorphism, xstream, xml-deserialization

I have an XML file which contains an array of Vehicles but I need to be able to deserialize it and take each object and put it in its own Vehicle.

For example this is what my XML file kinda looks like:

```
<Vehicle-array>
   <Car></Car>
   <Truck></Truck>
   <Van></Van>
</Vehicle-array>
```

So I need to be able to have the Car element be deserialized as a Car object not a `Vehicle` object.

I can get everything a `Vehicle[]` and each element is a specific `Vehicle` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them all in the Vehicle Array and then just cast them using the instanceof

```
if(a instanceof Car)
    a = (Car) a ;
else if(a instanceof Truck)
    ...
```

Comment: I was going to do it like this, but isn't this method frowned upon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB, but that's going to require that you have an XML schema.  From there you can run `xjc` to generate Java classes from the schema and then use the `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller` interfaces to build objects from XML.

Comment: I think his question is related to xstream (see the tag)

Comment: @ErikPragt Good catch.  I've never used xstream before, so I can't help with that.  I would be interested to know how it can deal with polymorphism.  I never really liked how JAXB did it.

Comment: I saw other posts recommending JAXB, but I need to to use XStream. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to create the classes, and annotate all the classes with the annotation @XStreamAlias, like this:

```
@XStreamAlias("Car")
class Car { }

@XStreamAlias("Truck")
class Truck { }
```

Most information can be found in [the documentation](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html). I'd suggest creating the classes first, then serialize to XML, that way it's easier to do the mapping.

Comment: I cannot change the classes.

Comment: Then you probably need to look at this: http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html